# Let $\mathbb F$ be a field, find a necessary and sufficient condition on $\mathbb F$ such that the only semi-polynomial maps are the polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field.

A map $f : \mathbb F^2 \rightarrow \mathbb F$ is semi-polynomial if for every fixed $y$ the map $ x \rightarrow f(x,y)$ is a polynomial and for every fixed $x$ the map $y \rightarrow f(x,y)$ is a polynomial.

I'm trying to find a necessary and sufficient condition on $\mathbb F$ such that the only semi-polynomial maps are the polynomials. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Nice question. Do you know an example of a map that is semi-polynomial, but not polynomial? Just so that we know what we are fighting against.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/606554/86856

Comment: @EricWofsey The proof in that paper should hold for any uncountable field, is that right?

Comment: @SantanaAfton: I haven't looked at the first paper, but the second paper proves the necessary and sufficient condition over arbitrary fields.  In any case, the argument in Jeremy Daniel's answer does work over any uncountable field.

Answer (score 0):

It follows from [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211297/is-a-bivariate-function-that-is-a-polynomial-function-with-respect-to-each-varia) that semi polynomials are polynomials iff $\mathbb{F}$ is not countable infinite.